# Data not swapping between two objects

Tags: objective-c, ios5

So I have this class that holds some values. In my viewcontroller I create a bunch of these objects and when I click on them I can set data to them. Then when I move them and the objects intersect I have a method that should swap data between them. Now when I step through it, everything seems to work fine. Self even holds the data from the other object but when I click on the object again it goes back to having its old data. Does anyone have any ideas why this would happen?

I set the data to each object by a pop up that needs to have OK clicked to set the data to that object, so I don't understand where it would be getting this data back from if I can clearly see that it does change it when I step through

Here is the method that swaps the data:

This happens on my touchesEnded method.

Seat.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomUIScrollView.h"
#import "PopOverViewController.h"

@interface Seat : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGRect rectangle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomUIScrollView *sv;

@property (assign) int seatId;
@property (assign) int seatsSelfObjectIndex;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *firstName;

@property (assign,nonatomic) CGColorRef selectedfillColor;

@property (nonatomic) int swapDataWithSeatInt;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Seat *swapDataWtihSeat;

@property (assign) CGPoint tempLoc;

@property (assign) BOOL didSeatIntersect;


@end




- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[self superview]];
    self.center = location;
    for (int i = 0; i < seats.count; i++)
         {
             if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.frame, [[seats objectAtIndex:i]frame]))
             {
                 if (i != seatsSelfObjectIndex)
                 {
                     swapDataWithSeatInt = i;
                     swapDataWtihSeat = [seats objectAtIndex:swapDataWithSeatInt];
                     didSeatIntersect = YES;
                 }
             }

         }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    selectedfillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    if (!didSeatIntersect)
    {
        [self setCenter:tempLoc];

    }
    else 
    {

        NSString *tempFirstName = [[seats objectAtIndex:swapDataWithSeatInt]firstName];

        [[seats objectAtIndex:swapDataWithSeatInt ] setFirstName:self.firstName];

       [self setFirstName:tempFirstName];

    } 
}
```

Comment: seats is a NSMutableArray that holds all of the added objects. On touchEnded I run a loop to see if any of the seat objects are touching and when they are I want them to swap data between eachother.

Comment: Well, the code you show does not seem to have problems. But your explanation of what you are doing is not very clear and the code you posted is totally out of context. I really do not know how to help you. Maybe post the declaration of the class you store in `seats` and the declaration of the class that implements the method you have shown (together with more info on that method, as it's not clear id `seats` is an ivar, a local, an argument, a global etc.)

Comment: All of this basically happens in the seat class. The seats(NSMuttableArray) is a global variable and each seat is added by the viewController. 
The data is added to the seat with a popover.
I added more of the seat class to show how and when this happens but I still don't understand why the data goes back to being what it was rather then holding on to the new data that was passed to it.

Comment: You should probably start NSLogging each time you do that swap. You may want to log `self` as an address, `[seats objectAtIndex: swapDataWithSeatInt]` as an address and then also dump the contents of `seat` (for each object NSLog at least the address and the firstName string). Looking at the data you logged may give you a hint.

Comment: thats a good idea. I'll try that out and see what I get. Thanks for the heads up.